# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un mensaje de salida desde un trigger?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy intentando crear un trigger que valide la cantidad de productos disponibles con la cantidad que el cliente desea comprar, sin embargo al ejecutar una inserción se realiza con normalidad por lo que no se esta ejecutando el trigger, quiero mandar un mensaje a consola para poder ver si se ejecuta o no, sin embargo no se como, en postgres usaba **raise notice**.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_check_stock_before
BEFORE INSERT ON ventas.ventas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE disponible INT;
    declare msg_error varchar(128);
    SELECT DISTINCT prod.cantidad INTO disponible FROM ventas.productos as prod
    INNER JOIN ventas ON prod.id_producto = ventas.id_producto
    WHERE prod.id_producto = 2;
    
    IF NEW.cantidadCompra > disponible THEN
        set msg_error = concat('TriggerErrorVentas: Cantidad comprada mayor a cantidad disponible.');
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg_error;
#   ELSE
    #   SELECT 'ERROR PRUEBA';
    END IF;
END //
```

Comment: El trigger si se me ejecuta pero me gustaria aprender a enviar mensajes en consola, gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué a consola? ¿No necesitarías una sesión abierta para ver los mensajes? ¿y no se mostrarían a todas las sesiones abiertas? ¿Por qué no a bitácora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql no tiene una sentencia especifica para mostrar un mensaje por consola, normalmente te sugeriría algo así:

```
SELECT 'Mesaje a mostrar' as '';
```

Pero en un trigger no es posible retornar un result set, por lo que creo que lo más sencillo sería implementar una tabla de auditoria:

```
CREATE TABLE Prueba (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TriggerDebug (
    ID  BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MSG VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_Prueba
BEFORE INSERT ON Prueba
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TriggerDebug(MSG) VALUES ('Mesaje a mostrar');
END;

INSERT INTO Prueba(nombre) VALUES('Bruno');

SELECT * FROM Prueba;
SELECT * FROM TriggerDebug;
```

Hay algunos que sugieren usar [`SIGNAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html), pero no me gusta mucho la idea por que no existe una señal del tipo informativo que sería lo que buscas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, queria hacerte otra pregunta ya que sabes del tema, para los triggers solo se pueden ejecutar en un solo evento? o puedo por ejemplo hacer que el trigger se ejecute en INSERT OR UPDATE para ahorrar tener que crear otro trigger.

Comment: Son triggers independientes, lo que eventualmente podrías hacer es unificar el código en un stored procedure e invocarlo en cada uno.